# Social preview on vue with google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, single-page-application

We have a Single Page Application (vue) for which we are trying to generate social previews with dynamic data. The social previews work everywhere except Facebook.

The web server is a node+express app served on GCP app engine

Each get request gets filtered based on user agent
if user agent is a crawler, serve a server-generated page with metadata
else if user agent is not a crawler, serve our Single Page Application (index.html)

it works fine if the web server is run locally, the facebook crawler gets served the correct page
but when hosted on GCP, if the facebook crawler gets /xyz, the logs show that it ALSO gets / (as in root) before /xyz, and the facebook crawler gets served both URLs, leading to an incorrect entry in the crawler

logs show:

GET / (no useragent)
GET /xyz (crawler useragent)
the first GET is wrong and should not happen
only happens on GCP

This is the code, with irrelevant parts removed:

```js
const express = require('express')
const path = require('path');
const port = process.env.PORT || 8081;
const app = express()
const nonSPArouter = express.Router();
const axios = require('axios');
const compression = require('compression');

app.use(compression());

nonSPArouter.get('/:roomId/', function (request, response) {
    console.log(request.params.roomId, request.headers['user-agent']);
    axios.get(FIREBASE_URL + request.params.roomId + '.json')
        .then(firebaseResponse => {
            // GET ROOM-SPECIFIC DATA
            ...

            response.render('bot', {
                img: img,
                url: URL,
                title: title,
                descriptionText: descriptionText,
                imageUrl: img
            });
            console.log('serving to bot', title);
        }).catch(error => {
            console.error(error);
        });
});

// serve static assets normally
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist'));

// handle every other route with index.html, which will contain
// a script tag to your application's JavaScript file(s).
app.get('*', function (request, response) {
    let userAgent = request.headers['user-agent'];
    console.log(`${request.url} user-agent: ${userAgent}`);
    if (/^(facebookexternalhit)|(Twitterbot)|(Pinterest)|(Discordbot)|(LinkedInBot)|(SkypeUriPreview)|(WhatsApp)/gi.test(userAgent)) {
        nonSPArouter(request, response);
    } else {
        console.log('serving index to', request.headers['user-agent']);
        response.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/index.html'));
    }
});

app.set('view engine', 'jade');
const server = app.listen(port, () => {
    const host = server.address().address;
    const port = server.address().port;

    console.log(`Webserver listening at http://${host}:${port}`)
})
```

This is what the logs on GCP show after manually doing a request with facebook's crawler, with green boxes indicating expected behavior, and the red boxes showing what is actually served to the facebook crawler:
[image: GCP logs]

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow. It would be easier to help if we could see the code snippet that does the differentiation :)

Comment: This behaviour is a bit strange and could be the case of something being hadled unproperly by App Engine, which is why I think you should open a report in [Google's Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187191&template=0) so that this can be checked.